# mvc .net visual studio 2012 rest api xml to json

Tags: json, xml, asp.net-mvc, rest, model-view-controller

I have a Get
this return me the result

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<FechaUpdate xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ImagenesGraciosas2.Models">
<FechaSegundos>635902782941643690</FechaSegundos>
<FechaSegundosBC>635902779020935030</FechaSegundosBC>
<FechaUpdateId>1</FechaUpdateId>
</FechaUpdate>
```

I add the image too

[image]

Well, when I

If I use content-type  json this only return me the attributes (not the object)

```
{
"FechaUpdateId": 1
"FechaSegundos": 635902782941643600
"FechaSegundosBC": 635902779020935000
}
```

I add the image

[image]

(I believe) the good result would be

```
{
  "FechaUpdate": {
    "FechaSegundos": "635902782941643690",
    "FechaSegundosBC": "635902779020935030",
    "FechaUpdateId": "1"
  }
}
```

because when I execute this on java

```
    FechaUpdate dto  = new Gson().fromJson(json, FechaUpdate.class);
```

all the attributes are in 0's (I believe) with the last json this is convert it fine.

How can I return the last result?

Comment: No ! You are getting the correct result. It is an JSON structure which represents your FechaUpdate class object. The object you received has all the properties(and it's values). What else are you looking for ? Why do you even expect your class name ?

Comment: When I try convert this json to object all the values are in 0's  I do it in java with this line:             FechaUpdate dto  = new Gson().fromJson(json, FechaUpdate.class);

Comment: Then I have done the right question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235721/gson-fromjsonjsonresult-myobject-class-return-values-in-0s