# Gson().fromJson(jsonResult, Myobject.class) return values in 0's

Tags: json, gson, android

I have this json

```
{"FechaUpdateId":1,"FechaSegundos":635902782941643690,"FechaSegundosBC":635902779020935030}
```

I execute this command for convert it to object

```
FechaUpdate dto  = new Gson().fromJson(json, FechaUpdate.class);
```

But I got this result

[image]

this is my FechaUpdate class

```
public class FechaUpdate {

    public int getFechaUpdateId() {
        return fechaUpdateId;
    }

    public void setFechaUpdateId(int fechaUpdateId) {
        this.fechaUpdateId = fechaUpdateId;
    }

    public long getFechaSegundosBC() {
        return fechaSegundosBC;
    }

    public void setFechaSegundosBC(long fechaSegundosBC) {
        this.fechaSegundosBC = fechaSegundosBC;
    }

    public long getFechaSegundos() {
        return fechaSegundos;
    }

    public void setFechaSegundos(long fechaSegundos) {
        this.fechaSegundos = fechaSegundos;
    }

        private int fechaUpdateId ;
        private long fechaSegundos ;
        private long fechaSegundosBC;



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

if you see my private attributes they are

```
        private int fechaUpdateId ;
        private long fechaSegundos ;
        private long fechaSegundosBC;
```

I change them by

```
private int FechaUpdateId ;
private long FechaSegundos ;
private long FechaSegundosBC;
```

and generate the getter and setters again.
the diference is the First letter is UpperCase.